# how to use GetConnectedClientsAsync from MQTTnet.Server in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, mqtt

I can host mqtt broker with MQTTnet nuget in asp.net core 2.2 by following code. I just want to show list of connected cliend in my controller and I found that GetConnectedClientsAsync method can be used. But I don't know how to use in core 2.2. Any suggestion.

In ConfigureServices

```
var mqttServerOption = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
                .WithDefaultEndpointPort(6261)                
                .WithConnectionValidator(Mqtt.connectionValidator.validator)
                .Build();
services.AddHostedMqttServer(mqttServerOption)
                .AddMqttConnectionHandler()
                .AddConnections()
                .AddMqttTcpServerAdapter();
```

In Configure

```
app.UseMqttEndpoint();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the solution.
just added controller constructor

```
private readonly MQTTnet.AspNetCore.MqttHostedServer mqttHostedServer;

public testController(MQTTnet.AspNetCore.MqttHostedServer mqttHostedServer)
{
        this.mqttHostedServer = mqttHostedServer;
}
```

and I can use it now.

```
var clients = await mqttHostedServer.GetClientStatusAsync();
```